# Доступ к динамическим элементам

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

У меня есть команда которая удаляет все что есть в контейнере, и класс Card, который при вызове метода render() добавляет в этот самый контейнер карточки товара:

```
document.querySelector('.es-catalog__cards-container').innerHTML = ''
Card('es-catalog__cards-container').render();
```

**На то  что нету слова new перед Card не обращайте внимания.**
Важно отметить, что метод render() обращается к json файлу и берет оттудова информацию о карточках товара, типа описания, названия и т.д. После чего, как я уже сказал, добавляет карточки в контейнер, в данном случаю в тег с классом <<es-catalog__cards-container>>.

Задача такова:
Мне нужно узнать количество этих карточек в контейнере после того как render() выполнит свою работу.

Я попробовал написать код сразу же после класса:

```
document.querySelector('.es-catalog__cards-container').innerHTML = ''
Card('es-catalog__cards-container').render();

// Новый код:
let count = document.querySelector('.es-catalog__cards-container').children.length
console.log(count);
```

И проблема в том что в консоли всегда выводится 0. Это происходит из-за того что методу render() требуется время на обращения к json файлу, на обработку всего этого и т.д. А код который ниже, не дожидается всего этого.

В итоге сперва контейнер очищается, потом метод render() начинает свою работу, а потом весь последующий код обращается к контейнеру и естественно получает 0, так как метод render() еще не успел добавит элементы в контейнер.

Как мне сделать так, что бы код:

```
let count = document.querySelector('.es-catalog__cards-container').children.length
console.log(count);
```

дождался выполнения этого кода:

```
Card('es-catalog__cards-container').render();
```

Пробовал с помощь callback функции и ничего не сработало. Не исключено что я просто неправильно пользовался callback, так как у меня еще нету опыта в этом. Если вы считаете что мою проблему может решить callback, то напишите пожалуйста свой пример.

Comment: Если Rendor  возвращает Promise, то почему бы вам не попробовать использовать именно асинхронный подход.  Например then, или из более современного  await. Эти команды явно говорят асинхронному коду,  ждать, пока что-то не загрузится. Как загрузилось - выполнять. Иными словами, я пока в магазине, ты меня жди, сейчас приду и пойдем дальше.

Comment: Другой вариант, если это не асинхронный код, то стоит переписать, или пойти более простым путем но не корректным. Вы можете использовать setTimeout, который даст возможность ждать то время, которое вы укажите, но почему этот подход страшный. Вы не узнаете когда будет выполнена операция и что если она будет выполнятся 3 секунды, а в setTimeout всего 2 секунды. Вы снова получите 0